# Second page of archive is empty

Tags: theme-development, pagination, archives

I'm developing my own theme and I included a pagination for the posts. In my database, there are 13 posts and I've set the maximum number of posts displayed on one page to 10, so I should have a second page.

The pagination is also displayed, so WordPress has recognized, that there are more posts than I want to display. But if I now move to the second page, I do not see the 3 remaining posts. The page is empty.

There is only an output for the header and the footer, but no post is output.

Does anyone know why this could happen? I'll give you more concrete information on how I did something if you need something, but unfortunately I don't have a clue, why this happens, so I don't really know what code to include. So feel free to ask :)

## Edit

The code of the archive is:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

  <div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

      <div class="container">
        <h2 class="page-title"><span><?php echo get_the_archive_title() ?></span></h2>
        <div class="row row-eq-height">
          <?php
          if ( have_posts() ):
            while( have_posts() ) : the_post();
              get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );
            endwhile;

            numeric_posts_nav(); // function from wpbeginner tutorial
          else:
            get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );
          endif;
          ?>
        </div><!-- .row -->
      </div><!-- .container -->

    </main>
  </div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Here is the tutorial for the numeric navigation: [wpbeginner](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-numeric-pagination-in-your-wordpress-theme/)

Comment: Without seeing the code for your archives template it isn't possible to answer this

Comment: @TomJNowell I added it

Answer (score 0):

How is the archive.php of your own theme looks like? Are you creating your theme based on underscore? You probably missing the get content part after the pagination. For example, here is part of the archive.php based on underscore theme:

```
if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <header class="page-header">
    <?php
    the_archive_title( '<h1 class="page-title">', '</h1>' );
    the_archive_description( '<div class="taxonomy-description">', '</div>' );
    ?>
    </header>
    <?php
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        get_template_part( 'components/post/content', get_post_format() );
    endwhile;
    the_posts_navigation();
else :
    get_template_part( 'components/post/content', 'none' );
endif; ?>
```

Comment: You were right, I didn't, but as you see in my code above, I have this included now, but it still does not work. :/

Comment: Try to change the `get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );` under the else part to be the same as your if part `get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none');`. your 'content' does not refer to the content.php which is located at 'template-parts' directory within your theme directory.

Comment: Okay, that works for the WordPress "post" post type (my blog) but not for any of my CPT. The numeric navigation says, that there are 10 pages (which is true) but if I visit any page different from the first one, I'm getting a Page not found.

Comment: On my CPT, I'm always redirected to the `index.php`, when trying to visit `.../page/2/` or else. In the `register_post_type()`function these parameters are set: `has_archive' => true` and `'rewrite' => array( 'pages'      => true )` Furthermore, I also have used `flush_rewrite_rules()` several times, to make sure, that the settings are active.

Comment: As far as your archive page problem is concerned, it is solved and you should marked this thread solved for the benefit of other future readers. I will suggest you post your Custom Post Type problem separately and share your code. It hard to diagnostic like this but my gut feeling is that that you either have a broken single.php or have wrong settings in permalink and .htaccess.